# UIBarButtonItem Setting Size for System Icons

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIToolbar` with a number of buttons (back, forward, refresh, action) separated by flexible space.

I am toggling between a `UIBarButtonItem` with `UIBarButtonSystemItemStop` and a `UIBarButtonItem` with `UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh` but this is causing the icons to move position ever so slightly (apparently the refresh and stop icons are different size).

Any way I can force the `UIBarButtonItem` sizes to be the same? I tried setting the `width` property but it didn't change the system anything on the System Item style buttons.

Please help! Thanks!

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving to fixed separators to fix this strange problem.